# Pass data to another element and be able to edit it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Whenever I click on the edit button, I have a textarea which I want to update the value above, however I have an issue to get the text from above to be displayed in the textarea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORrTe.png)

I tried solving this like this, but doesn't seem to work. Can someone advice?

```html
<p> {{ points.singlePoint?.description }}</p>
Edit icon here.
  <textarea>
     placeholder="Add chapter description...",
     v-model="newDescriptionData",
     v-if="updateDescriptionWindow == true"
  </textarea>
```

```js
    const newDescriptionData = ref(points.singlePoint.description)

return {
   points,
   newDescriptionData
 }
```

Comment: Maybe it is just a copy any paste error, but you are closing the textarea opening tag before you have the attributes. And did you just omit the `updateDescriptionWindow` which you check to display the texarea?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at an official guide, it might help
[Vue.js guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)